# XML not well formed Android keeps showing up

Tags: android, xml, well-formed

I have a XML-File in an application I just downloaded an it and eclipse keeps telling me that it is not well formed. I can not see any problem with the syntax (I even checked it with the xml validator w3schools which couldn't find any errors either.

Thank you very much in advance, here is the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
 -->

<PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:settings="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.android.settings"
android:title="@string/dock_settings_title"
android:key="parent">


<!-- 
<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="dock_audio"
    android:title="@string/dock_audio_settings_title"
    android:summary="@string/dock_settings_summary"
   android:widgetLayout="@*android:layout /preference_dialog" />


<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="dock_sounds"
    android:title="@string/dock_sounds_enable_title"
    android:summaryOn="@string/dock_sounds_enable_summary_on"
    android:summaryOff="@string/dock_sounds_enable_summary_off"
    android:defaultValue="false" />
    -->

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Try _Clear Lint Warnings_ and/or _Clean Project_.

Comment: I've tried your XML in Eclipse, and no error shows up...

Comment: What is the exact error/warning message?

Comment: @Jens How do exectute "Clear Lint Warnings"??

Comment: @Bigflow teh extact message is"error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)"

Comment: _Clear Lint Warnings/Markers_ can be performed via the Checkbox icon in the Eclipse toolbar (http://tools.android.com/recent/neweclipselintui).

Comment: @Matze I don't get any error. I would suggest to delete the xml file, and make a new android XML layout (file -> new -> other -> android -> android XML layout)

Answer (score 0):

In Your Commented Code Your `PreferenceScreen` Closed before `CheckBoxPreference`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <PreferenceCategory
                android:title="First Category">
                <CheckBoxPreference
                        android:title="Checkbox Preference"
                        android:defaultValue="false"
                        android:summary="This preference can be true or false"
                        android:key="checkboxPref" />
                <ListPreference
                        android:title="List Preference"
                        android:summary="This preference allows to select an item in a array"
                        android:key="listPref"
                        android:defaultValue="digiGreen"
                        android:entries="@array/listArray"
                        android:entryValues="@array/listValues" />
        </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Look at this link . http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences

Comment: @Matze, try with my posted xml file and link .